# How to set the default position of a scrollable DIV?

Tags: css, scroll-snap

I'm using `scroll-snap-type` to move through DIVs and put them into view. What I want to do is set the view to the 2nd DIV by default, so when the page loads the div with "This should be viewed by default" is seen, and then the user is able to scroll left or right.

How can I do this with just CSS? (no JS)

https://jsfiddle.net/2hcgoL1b/2/

```css
html, body, .holster {
  height: 100%;
}


.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex: none;
}

.container.x {
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}


/* scroll-snap */
.x.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}


.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: none;
}

.x.container > div {
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
}






/* appearance fixes */
.y.container > div:first-child {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 64px;
}
/* coloration */
.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #87EA87;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #87CCEA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container x mandatory-scroll-snapping" dir="ltr">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>This should be viewed by default</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there was a trick : `<div tabindex="0" autofocus="autofocus">` but not sure it still works . It was much more annoying than helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `javascript`, `tabindex` attribute and an `id` , **CSS won't be of any help here**:

disclaimer *it will be annoying for your visitors such as was the old trick  `<div tabindex="0" autofocus="autofocus">`*

```js
window.onload= document.getElementById("focus").focus();
```

```css
/* setup */
html, body, .holster {
  height: 100%;
}


.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex: none;
}

.container.x {
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}


/* scroll-snap */
.x.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}


.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: none;
}

.x.container > div {
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 128px;
}






/* appearance fixes */
.y.container > div:first-child {
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 64px;
}
/* coloration */
.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #87EA87;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #87CCEA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container x mandatory-scroll-snapping" dir="ltr">
  <div>1</div>
  <div tabindex="0" id="focus">This should be viewed by default</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

to allow element to get the focus, if it is not a link or a form element, an attribute will be necessary.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex
>
> The tabindex global attribute indicates that its element can be focused, and where it participates in sequential keyboard navigation (usually with the Tab key, hence the name).

**Note:** once the element has an `id`, you should be able to link it : `http://site.html#MyId`